# Do a task for a 1 minute interval telethon

Tags: python, bots, telethon

```
async def main():
    me = await client.get_me()

    await client.send_message(####, 'Hello')


with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I want to run the code above every 1 minute, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution using [asyncio sleep](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping):

```
from asyncio import sleep

async def main():
    while True:
        me = await client.get_me()

        await client.send_message(####, 'Hello')
        await sleep(60) # sleep for a min

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

We use loops, In order to do the same task multiple times, You can consider while loop for this.

```
import asyncio


async def main():
    me = await client.get_me()

    while True:  # True will make sure loop will run infinite time
        await client.send_message("me", 'Hello')
        await asyncio.sleep(60)  # `.sleep` will make your code sleep for x ammout of seconds. 


with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: This will not work, because `await` can't be put outside of `async def`, and because `asyncio.sleep` needs to be `await`'ed.

Comment: @Lonami my bad! OP wants to do the same task multiple times so I was more focused on the loop, btw I have edited my answer :)